# Html column width is too much Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```js
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById("cc");
  var statementDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var statementName = document.createElement("div");
  // var removeIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
  // removeIconDiv.className = "col w-25";
  // removeIconDiv.setAttribute(
  //   "style",
  //   "padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; width: 10px !important;"
  // );
  // statementDiv.appendChild(removeIconDiv);
  var trashcan = document.createElement("span");
  trashcan.className = "ml-4 col bi bi-trash";
  trashcan.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; width: 10px !important;"
  );
  // removeIconDiv.appendChild(trashcan);
  statementDiv.appendChild(trashcan);
  statementDiv.appendChild(statementName);
  statementDiv.className = "mb-3 option row text-left";

  /* STATEMENT NAME ************************ */
  statementName.className = "ml-2 col-2";
  statementName.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", "Your Statement");
  statementName.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; width: 110px;"
  );
  statementName.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
  /***************************************** */

  /* RADIO BUTTONS* ************************ */
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var radioTemp = document.createElement("div");
    radioTemp.className = "col text-center";
    radioTemp.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "margin-right: 3px !important; width: 110px;"
    );
    var temp = document.createElement("input");
    temp.className = "form-check-input";
    temp.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    temp.setAttribute("name", "2");
    temp.setAttribute("disabled", "true");

    radioTemp.appendChild(temp);
    statementDiv.appendChild(radioTemp);
  }
  /***************************************** */

  parentDiv.appendChild(statementDiv);
```

```html
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Survey Creator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vanessa.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.5.6/css/ionicons.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

<div id="cc"></div>
```

I have this `span`:

```
 var trashcan = document.createElement("span");
  trashcan.className = "ml-4 col bi bi-trash";
  trashcan.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important; width: 10px !important;"
  );
```

It basically is a trashcan icon, which later on I want to be clickable and do some action.
My problem is that it is too wide as we can see here:

[image]

[image]

I guess it's some attribute of Bootstrap's `col` but I tried to overwrite using `width: 10px !important;` but still it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can make the width be as big as the icon inside? I also tried `width: fit-content` but still didn't work. Thanks

Comment: The orange part you see is margin-left. This is one thing you should take a look at. Considering your width, `img` are `inline` elements which do not support width adjustments. Try switching to `inline-block` and post what happens please.

Comment: I know, I added that with `ml-4`. My point is that the blue part is too big

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your problem via a snippet, so we can have a better understanding of whats happening? [Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @IISkullsII i did

Comment: Ah i see, the normal `width` is ignored. Try it with `max-width` instead. That might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue is the set Flex-Options like `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` as those overwrite the `width` options dynamicly to adapt to the window width.

You can either set the `max-width` to your desired value or remove the set values via `flex-shrink: initial;` and `flex-grow: initial;`

Answer (score 2):

The size of the column comes from the `flex` property. You can set it to `initial` and set `width:fit-content`

```css
.col:first-child{
  flex:initial;
  width:fit-content;
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><span class="bi bi-trash"></span></div>
  <div class="col">A</div>
  <div class="col">A</div>
  <div class="col">A</div>
</div>
```